# merge multiple nodes with the same relationship

Tags: neo4j

anybody can help me with

```
MATCH(n:Customer)-[r:ORDERS]->(o:Order)<-[r1:ORDERS]-(n1:Customer)
WITH COLLECT(n)+COLLECT(n1) as nodes
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(nodes,{mergeRels:true}) YIELD node
RETURN node
```

I actually want to combine n and n1 because let's say n has "name" property and n2 has "email" property. I tried the code above and it says: "Neo.ClientError.Schema.ConstraintValidationFailed" with explanation: "Cannot delete node<1397>, because it still has relationships. To delete this node, you must first delete its relationships."

I've found the solution:

```
//SOLUTION
MATCH(n:Customer)-[r:ORDERS]->(o:Order)<-[r1:ORDERS]-(n1:Customer)
WITH o.order_id as i, HEAD(COLLECT([n,n1])) AS nodes
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(nodes, {mergeRels:true})
YIELD node
RETURN node
```

it works perfectly to all nodes referred as n and n1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of collect(n) + collect(n1), use head(collect[n, n1])).  Also, you should include combine properties in your parameter.

```
OLD:
MATCH(n:Customer)-[r:ORDERS]->(o:Order)<-[r1:ORDERS]-(n1:Customer)
WITH COLLECT(n)+COLLECT(n1) as nodes
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(nodes,{mergeRels:true}) YIELD node
RETURN node

New:
MATCH(n:Customer)-[r:ORDERS]->(o:Order)<-[r1:ORDERS]-(n1:Customer)
WITH head(collect([n,n1])) as nodes
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(nodes,{properties:"combine",mergeRels:true}) YIELD node
RETURN node
```

I'm using neo4j version 4.2.4 and below is my sample test data;

```
CREATE (c1:Customer {name: "Charlize Theron"})
CREATE (c2:Customer {email: "char@theron.com"})
CREATE (o:Order {ID: 1234})
MERGE  (c1)-[:ORDERS]->(o)
MERGE  (c2)-[:ORDERS]->(o)
MERGE  (c2)-[:LIKES]->(o)
```

Reference: https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.2/graph-updates/graph-refactoring/merge-nodes/

Comment: I've tried the HEAD(), however it works only for two nodes(1 pair), while I want to merge all n and n1. I tried to run it 4 times, worked only for 4 pairs. Is there any way to iterate through for all pairs of nodes? Before I reload the CSV file using MERGE like you suggested.

Comment: If it works for n and n1, please accept the answer to your original question. Then ask again for 4 pairs. thanks.

Comment: Ok I've accepted it, any ideas to apply the to the whole nodes instead of only 2 nodes?

Comment: NVM, its solved.